# sequelize-auto pass underscore parameter to all models generated

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

new to nodejs, I am playing around with [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) and [sequelize-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto).
I have a small problem in the fact that I would like sequelize-auto to set the [sequelize](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/sequelize/) [options.underscored=false] to true.

I read on the sequelize-auto docs that I should be able to pass a config object when generating the models, but so far no luck.
This is what i run:

`sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d <my_db> -h <my_host> -u root -p 3306 -x <my_password> -e mysql -c sequelize.config.json`

from the directory where sequelize.config.json sits.

`sequelize.config.json` looks like this

```
{
  "options" : {
     "underscored" : true
  }
}
```

I also tried without the options 'wrapping'.

I need it because I am working on an already existing database and I would prefer not to edit it.

The error I am dealing with at the moment is

`Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'createdAt' in 'field list'`

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Ah.. I was almost there, but I am a bit dumb so...
The command i need to run is:

`sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d <my_db> -h <my_host> -u root -p 3306 -x <my_password> -e mysql -a sequelize.config.json`

The only difference is that I needed to use the `-a` instead of `-c`.

It is pretty well explained [here under Usage header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto)...

Read the docs!!!